# Trying to identify movie of estranged father saving his daughter with government chip in his head

Tags: story-identification, movie

Live action movie. With unfamiliar actors, the main protagonist was a disheveled blond/dirty blonde male. The quality of the movie seemed to be 2007-2010, low-budget. I believe I saw it on Netflix 2012-2016.

The movie starts with establishing that a man lives alone and is estranged from his daughter/s. He is essentially an alcoholic and gets abducted or implanted with a government chip, because he is someone that wouldn't be sought after or worried about.

The chip may not be necessarily in his brain, I believe it may be more like an eye implant. A shadowy government figure can talk to him through it and show him images. He is shown his daughter has been kidnapped or at least he is shown images to be compelled to believe that she has been harmed and to do things he normally wouldn't. He initially believes it to be God or is told it is God.

He reluctantly agrees to things the voice is telling him and has to try multiple times to steal some protected intelligence from a corporate/government person's home. One of the first things he's tasked to do is find an alley and retrieve a briefcase and/or shoots and kills a woman trying to do so.

The movie tropes on his alcoholism and estranged relationship while he laments about the person/god in his head. When he finally uncovers the conspiracy of the voice and their tasks, I believe he gets an opportunity to use the intelligence/device on himself which turns him into some sort of omnipotent or higher being. The memory I have is that his body is sort of blue but larger like a nervous system. Spanning the skies, becoming ethereal and God-like he is able to make the choice to "save" his daughter by being this new entity.

Comment: It feels like *Upgrade*, but the plot doesn't quite line up.

Comment: Whenever I search most movies that come up are those action types like Upgrade or Total Recall. The budget of the actors/movie didn't lend itself to be really considered action heavy. There were some gun standoffs but the chip was more of a recording/AV implant rather than a human upgrade chip. Until after he discovered the government conspiracy.